# Adobe Air GUI Question

Tags: windows, user-interface, air, adobe

I am new to Adobe Air and I have just started to learn. I am using FlexBuilder 3 to build a desktop app with Adobe Air. I am a bit confused with the GUI development. The app I am building has multiple input screens. What are the best practices for this type of app in terms of windows and input screens?

Should I use the `Viewstack` navigator to show and hide different screens within the app or is it better to create a new .mxml file for each input screen?

I am used to Visual Basic development and the concept of one form per input screen.  I am having trouble figuring out how GUI development works in Air/Flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the code of all the controls directly to the `ViewStack` in the main application, declare them as separate mxml controls and use those controls in the viewstack.

Instead of

```
<mx:ViewStack>
  <mx:Canvas>
    <!-- contents of control 1 -->
  </mx:Canvas>
  <mx:VBox>
    <!-- contents of control 2 -->
  </mx:VBox>
  <mx:HBox>
    <!-- contents of control 3 -->
  </mx:HBox>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Do:

```
<!-- MainApp.mxml -->
<mx:ViewStack>
  <local:Control1/>
  <local:Control2/>
  <local:Control3/>
</mx:ViewStack>

<!-- Control1.mxml -->
<mx:Canvas>
  <!-- contents of control 1 -->
</mx:Canvas>

<!-- Control2.mxml -->
<mx:VBox>
  <!-- contents of control 2 -->
</mx:VBox>

<!-- Control3.mxml -->
<mx:HBox>
  <!-- contents of control 3 -->
</mx:HBox>
```

And there is a [Window class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Window.html) in AIR, if you haven't noticed it already